# Order of infinitesimal $\int_0^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, infinitesimals

How could I find the right order of infinitesimal of

$$\int_0^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr,\qquad c_1,c_2>0,$$

as $|x|$ tends to $+\infty$? Should it be trivial? For an upper bound, I tried something like

\begin{align}
\int_0^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr&=\int_0^{|x|}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr+\int_{|x|}^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr\\
&\leq \frac{e^{-c_2|x|}}{c_1}(1-e^{-c_1|x|})+e^{-c_1|x|}\int_{|x|}^{|x|^2}e^{-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr\\
&=\frac{e^{-c_2|x|}}{c_1}(1-e^{-c_1|x|})+|x|^2e^{-c_1|x|}\int_1^{|x|}\frac{e^{-c_2t}}{t^2}dt
\end{align}

and the order of the upper bound should be $|x|^2e^{-c_1|x|}$ or $e^{-c_2|x|}$, depending on whose bigger between $c_1$ and $c_2$, and for a lower bound
\begin{align}
\int_0^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr&=\int_0^{|x|}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr+\int_{|x|}^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1 r-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr\\
&\geq e^{-c_1|x|}\int_0^{|x|}e^{-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr+e^{-c_2|x|}\int_{|x|}^{|x|^2}e^{-c_1r}dr\\
&=e^{-c_1|x|}\int_0^{|x|}e^{-c_2\frac{|x|^2}{r}}dr+\frac{e^{-c_2|x|}}{c_1}(e^{-c_1|x|}-e^{-c_1|x|^2})\\
&=|x|^2e^{-c_1|x|}\int_{|x|}^\infty \frac{e^{-c_2t}}{t^2}dt+\frac{e^{-c_2|x|}}{c_1}(e^{-c_1|x|}-e^{-c_1|x|^2})\\
\end{align}

where I don't exactly know how to handle $\int_{|x|}^\infty \frac{e^{-c_2t}}{t^2}dt$.

Thank you

Comment: Take $r = x u$. Then Laplace's method gives
$$\int_0^{x^2} e^{-c_1 r - c_2 x^2/r} dr =
x \int_0^x e^{x \phi(u)} du \sim
x \int_{\mathbb R} e^{x (\phi(u_0) + \phi''(u_0) u^2/2)} du,$$
where $u_0 = \sqrt {c_2/c_1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One integration by parts gives
$$\int\frac{e^{-ct}}{t^2}\,dt=-c\,\text{Ei}(-c t)-\frac{e^{-c t}}{t}$$ where appears the exponential integral function.
$$\int_{|x|}^\infty \frac{e^{-ct}}{t^2}\,dt=c\, \text{Ei}(-c |x|)+\frac{e^{-c |x|}}{|x|}$$ Assuming $x>0$, the expansion would give
$$\sim\frac{e^{-c |x|}}{c x^2}$$